# HTML DOM .innerHTML Property value not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to get a message to display when a radio button is chosen and the processRadioButtons function is called.

In Safari - Mac, I don't see the message at all. In Chrome and Firefox, I see it but only for a second. I also tried using the .innerHTML method [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_elmnt_innerhtml) and pasted in my line:

```
            document.getElementById("method_message").innerHTML = "You selected a method";
```

with their code and the text worked fine there in Safari Mac and stayed on the page.

Does anyone know why the text is not appearing or not appearing very long?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function processRadioButtons() {

        if(document.frmFrequentMethods.frequentMethod[0].checked  == true) 
        {
            document.getElementById("method_message").innerHTML = "You selected a method";
        }
    }

    </script>

<style type="text/css"> 
input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name = "frmFrequentMethods">
    <fieldset> <legend>Frequently Used Transportation Methods</legend>      
         </p>
            <input type="radio" name="frequentMethod" value="car" checked = "checked">car
            <input type="radio" name="frequentMethod" value="walk">walk
            <input type="radio" name="frequentMethod" value="bike">bike
             <SPAN STYLE=color:blue ID="method_message"></SPAN>

         </p>    
        <input type="submit" value="Get Method of Transportation" onClick="processRadioButtons()">   
    </fieldset> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The form is being submitted by your "submit" `<input>` so the page is being reloaded.

Comment: As an aside, you should be using `.textContent` for displaying messages rather than `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Hi Pointy: I don't understand your comment about submit as I need the submit to evaluate their choice right? and the submit happens before the processRadioButtons() function call in which the .innerHTML is used, right?

Comment: Is there another way to submit the form to avoid the page refresh? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to investigate AJAX.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the tip. I'm going to investigate this article unless you have a different suggestion: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59.   Thanks

Comment: You need to either open or remove the `</p>` tags and add quotes around the style property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out in comments, What you have is a `submit` button. Clicking it will submit the form and the entire page will be refreshed.

As i understood from the comments, If you want to give feedback once a radio button is selected, you can use it's `onclick` event instead of the submit buttons click to do the same thing as follows.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="frequentMethod" value="car" onClick="processRadioButtons(this)" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="frequentMethod" value="walk" onClick="processRadioButtons(this)">walk
<input type="radio" name="frequentMethod" value="bike" onClick="processRadioButtons(this)">bike
```

JS

```
function processRadioButtons(elm) {
 var message = document.getElementById("method_message");
 if(elm.value  == "car") 
   message.innerHTML = "You selected a method";
 else
   message.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Hi Tilwin:  I get the idea of the code you provided but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't think the onClick event is working as I placed alerts inside the function and never see them fired.

Comment: @Jazzmine Well it's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/25sGk/)... btw avoiding inline styles and caps from html markup is a really good practice...

Comment: Thank you for providing the fiddle. Works like a champ. I agree about the css in html, was doing it for testing.